# JavaScript Throws Undefined Error

Tags: javascript, undefined

What it is supposed to do - 
Example

```
url1(pages,"ALT") returns "www.xyz.ac.uk" 
url1(pages,"xyz") returns ""
```

The error - `TypeError: Cannot call method 'toUpperCase' of undefined`

This is just for some coursework, Im stuck with these errors. Any help would be much appreciated

```
function index(string,pattern,caseSensitive) {
    if(caseSensitive == false) {
        var v = string.toUpperCase();
    } else {
        var v = string;
    }

    return indexNumber = v.indexOf(pattern);
}
var pages = [ "|www.lboro.ac.uk|Loughborough University offers degree programmes and world class research.", "!www.xyz.ac.uk!An alternative University" , "%www%Yet another University"];

    alert(url1(pages, "ALT"));

function url1(pages,pattern) {
    var siteContent = [];
    for(i=0;i<pages.length;i++) {
        var seperator = pages[i].charAt(0);
        if(pages[i].indexOf(seperator)>0){
            siteContent = pages[i].split(pages[i].indexOf(seperator));      
        }
        if( index(siteContent[2],pattern,false)>=0){
            return siteContent[1]; 
        }else{
            return "";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Try to use a different variable than "string" such as "str".  Even through "string" isn't a reserved word, it is still a built-in object and javascript might be getting confused.

Comment: @Michael: `string` isn't. `String` _is_ (though I still wouldn't use that name, for confusion for use of the actual constructor).

Answer (score 2):

```
    if(pages[i].indexOf(seperator)>0){
        siteContent = pages[i].split(pages[i].indexOf(seperator));      
    }
    if( index(siteContent[2],pattern,false)>=0){
        return siteContent[1]; 
    }else{
        return "";
    }
```

If `pages[i].indexOf(seperator)<=0`, `siteContent` is still whatever it was from the last iteration.  If that happens on the first iteration, `siteContent` is still `[]`, and `siteContent[2]` is `undefined`.

Another problem: the expression `pages[i].indexOf(seperator)` returns a number, and `pages[i].split` expects a delimiting string as an argument.  Since the number doesn't appear in your input, you'll always get a single-element array, and `siteContent[2]` will always be `undefined`.  Get rid of `.indexOf(seperator)`, change it to `siteContent = pages[i].split(seperator)`.

One more: get rid of the `else { return ""; }`.  Add a `return "";` after the `for` loop.

Finally, in the first `if` statement condition, change `.indexOf(seperator) > 0` to `.indexOf(seperator, 1) !== -1`.  Since you're getting `seperator` from the first character of the string, it will be found at `0`.  You want the second occurrence, so start the search at `1`.  In addition, `.indexOf` returns `-1` if it doesn't find the substring.  You'll need to account for this in both `if` conditions.

Side note, as this is not causing your problem: never use `== false`.  JS will coerce stuff like `0` and `""` to `== false`.  If that's what you want, just use the `!` operator, because the expression has nothing to do with the value `false`.

My final answer is http://jsfiddle.net/QF237/

Comment: Haha, you've been tricked yourself: `void 0 == false` is `false`. Don't worry, I've fell for that myself before.

Comment: @sqykly I dont understand, how would I go changing this??

Comment: @user2964960 move the second `if` statement inside the first.  Add `return ""` after the statement or add `else { return ""; }` (with appropriate line breaks and indentation), whichever you prefer.

Comment: @sqykly I have made the changes and it still is not working, do you mind checking the link I sent you as I might not have understood what you said. http://jsfiddle.net/27Jt8/1/   Thanks again, sorry newbie

Comment: @sqykly If you cant edit it on the link, just paste it here mate. Sorry for the trouble

Comment: @user2964960 Tested sqykly's fiddle and there's always a match, even for incorrect inputs. Don´t know if that worked for you; anyway, here´s my fiddle if you want to take a look. http://jsfiddle.net/zfD9m/2/

Comment: @user2964960 I went back to my fiddle and found that the edits didn't stick.  Updated with a link that definitely works.

Answer (score 1):

Right here:

```
alert(url1(pages, ALT)); // ALT ISN'T DEFINED
```

I believe you forgot to quote it:

```
alert(url1(pages, "ALT"));
```

Comment: I have changed it but I now get this error - TypeError: Cannot call method 'toUpperCase' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

You should split the string passing the separator character itself. Your function then will look like:

```
function url1(pages,pattern) {
    var siteContent = [];
    for(i=0;i<pages.length;i++) {
        var seperator = pages[i].charAt(0);
        console.log(seperator);
        if(pages[i].indexOf(seperator)>=0){ 
            siteContent = pages[i].split(seperator);   //fixed here   
        }
        console.log(siteContent);
        if( index(siteContent[2],pattern,false)>=0){
            return siteContent[1]; 
        }else{
            return "";
        }    
    }
}
```

Tell us if it worked, please.

EDIT: It seeems your index() also has a little problem. Please try the function below.

```
function index(string,pattern,caseSensitive) {
    var v;
    if(caseSensitive == false) {
        v = string.toUpperCase();
        pattern = pattern.toUpperCase(); //to clarify: pattern should be uppercased also if caseSensitiveness is false
    } else {
        v = string;
    }
    return v.indexOf(pattern);
}
```

EDIT 2:

And url1() is finally like this:

```
function url1(pages,pattern) {
    var siteContent = [];
    for(i=0;i<pages.length;i++) {
        var seperator = pages[i].charAt(0);
        if(pages[i].indexOf(seperator)>=0){
            siteContent = pages[i].split(seperator);      
        }
        if( index(siteContent[2],pattern,false)>=0){
            return siteContent[1]; 
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

In this case, the first occurrence of pattern in all pages will be returned.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, your suggestion weirdly works with onsole.log(url1(pages,"Loughborough")); and the correct site is returned. However for anything else even onsole.log(url1(pages,"Loug")); (which theoretically should return the same value) it does not work.

Comment: This is what I currently have

Comment: Made some changes to index. Please take a look. I have tested a couple times here and it seems ok.